# Тестрование API REST с предварительным запуском приложения, используя Spring MockMvc

Tags: spring, api, rest, rest-assured

Пишу автотесты для API запросов на RestAssured.

Необходимо настроить предварительный запуск приложения перед запуском тестов,
используя RestController. Чтобы тесты обращались к mock и прогоняли необходимые Post, Get запросы.

Спасибо !

Comment: Непонятно, если приложение запущено, то что мокать собираетесь?

Comment: Приложение не запущено

Comment: Вопрос в том, что если вы хотите запускать приложение перед запуском тестов, то что имеете ввиду, когда пишете  `тесты обращались к mock`? Уточнение вопроса делайте не в комментарии, а модифицируйте текст вопроса.